# How can I pass 2 byte[] from JNI to Java

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I have a java method, like this:

```
public static native void receiveCallback(byte[] value1, byte[] value2);
```

In JNI I can reach the class and I can reach the method, but my parameter list is incorrect. I am trying to call the method like this:

```
jmethodID testJavaMethod = (java_environment)->GetMethodID(clazz, "receiveCallback","([B[B");
```

I then get a NoSuchMethod exception at runtime.

I followed multiple SO questions, including this one [JNI - How to callback from C++ or C to Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9630134/jni-how-to-callback-from-c-or-c-to-java), but I'm still stuck.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: The descriptor for this method is `([B[B)V` not `([B[B`

Comment: Still same exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no method with name='receiveCallback' signature='([B[B)V' in class L…../LibClass;

Comment: The way you've written it, "receiveCallback" looks like it's an abstract method. That can't work. Can you post more of your code?

Comment: The method is not abstract. I added the way the method exists in java. The purpose is to just pass these 2 const char* values from c to java.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to call back into Java, the implementation must be in Java. You need

```
public static void receiveCallback(byte[] value1, byte[] value2) {
    // do something with value1 and value2
}
```

And to get the id of a static method you need to use "GetStaticMethodID". Also to call it you will have to use "CallStaticVoidMethod()".