# How to call an application from android native application

Tags: android, c++

Here what i have three application:

1. UI application (Java)
2. Native application A (Cpp)
3. Native application B (Cpp)

Now UI application call Native application A start.
So is there any way to call B start from A?
Because B is external part of A, it's needed to be individual process.

Update:
Call app like this:

```
std::system("am start -n com.package.name/.activity")
```

it's work in ADB, but not work in Native application.

New idea:
Because B application just need to do a simple file transfer job(OTA file download).
So I think i need to make B application become a service. And make it start when system boot. Then A application not invoke B but broadcast an intent to B.Like this:

```
std::system("am broadcast -a my_start_action -n com.package.name/.activity")
```

But still not work.

Answer (score 0):

You should use JNI callback to ask application A send start intent to application B.

JNI callback :

[JNI - How to callback from C++ or C to Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9630134/jni-how-to-callback-from-c-or-c-to-java)

send start intent to application B:

[Open another application from your own (intent)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2780102/open-another-application-from-your-own-intent)

Answer (score 0):

Since `A` and `B` are native Linux process, you can start B from A by using

`system` or `fork`/`exec` api.

In the code of A
`system("/path/to/b")`

Or in code of A `fork()` a process, and them `exec("/path/to/b", ...)`