# JNI/Kotlin: Is it possible to pass delegate to JNI?

Tags: java, c++, kotlin, java-native-interface

I'm working JNI and I wonder is it possible to communicate via `delegate`.

for example:

**Kotlin**

```
typealias MessageReceived = (msg: String) -> Unit

external fun RegisterCallback(callback: MessageReceived)
```

**C++ (JNI)**

```cpp
JNIEXPORT void Java_some_package_name_Foo_RegisterCallback(JNIEnv* env, jobject, void (*MessageReceived)(jstring msg)) {
    if (MessageReceived != nullptr) {
        char buffer[260] = {0};
        sprintf(buffer, "Callback registered!");
        jstring messageJStr = env->NewStringUTF(buffer);
        MessageReceived(messageJStr);
        env->DeleteLocalRef(messageJStr);
    }
}
```

is it impossible?

When I ran this code, I can't access and get SIGSEGV (address access protected).

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9630134/jni-how-to-callback-from-c-or-c-to-java), but it seems to complicated to me.

Thank you for your interest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

Type of your `MessageReceived` should be `jobject`.

To invoke delegate you need:

- find `MessageReceived` class by `GetObjectClass`
- find method (I'm not sure what is method name here) by `GetMethodID`
- invoke it using `CallVoidMethod`

You can find example [here](http://journals.ecs.soton.ac.uk/java/tutorial/native1.1/implementing/method.html)

Comment: I mean, without jmethodID or something.

Comment: You can't call java method without "jmethodID or something" :)

Comment: I also found about `CallXXXMethod`, but it should be target method defined in native call wrapping class.

I wonder is it possible to invoke delegate by passing it. Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: All `CallXXXMethod` work the same way. Only difference is type of called method.